# Unable to start calculating this voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider

I'm trying to solve all kinds of voltage dividers for an upcomming exam, but I'm stuck in this one. I've solved it in LTSpice, but I cannot solve it on paper.

LTSpice showed me, that the Ux=3V, but closest to that, I got to 3.333V (which I got from a voltage divider equation Ux = (5V*2000)/(1000+2000)).

I need just a "kick" for the start on how to start solving dividers as this one.

[image]

Comment: Nodal analysis is easiest in this case: \$\small(U-5)\large +\frac{U}{2}+\frac{U-2}{2}=0 \$

Comment: Suggestion: Draw all your voltage sources the right way up (positive on top) and grounds pointing to, ehm, ground, i.e. downwards. It helps visualisation.

Comment: Certanly did! And it helped a lot as well. I was just confused due to not knowing the potential in the middle, as the current could flow to 2V (that's where I got confused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert voltage sources to current sources. One is 5 mA and the other is 1 mA. They will then be both in parallel with a resistor of value equal to the parallel combination of R20 and R22. And all of that will be parallel to R21. Enough of a kick?

That solves to 3 volts without using a calculator.

Comment: Hmm...yup, kinda. But I did it a slightly different and got the right result!
Since the GND is the lowest potential in this circuit, currents from both Voltage sources must flow towards GND. So I've written:

((2v-UX)/2000) + ((5V-Ux)/1000) = UX/2000

Which are just currents I(r20) + I(22) = I(r21), then just scrambled the equation and got the right value. 

Certainly a useful hint! Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to solve this sort of thing is with this generalization of the voltage divider formula:

Vo = \$(\frac {V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_2}{R_2} +..+ \frac{V_n}{R_n})(R_1||R_2||..||R_n)\$

The second term is \$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1K} + \frac{1}{2K} + \frac{1}{2K}}\$ = 0.5K  (the three resistors in parallel)

The first term is \$\frac{5V}{1K} + \frac{2V}{2K} + \frac{0V}{2K}\$ = 6mA

Then the result is 6mA \$\cdot\$ 0.5K = 3V